# Multiplexing four 2 digit 7-segment display low brightness

Tags: pi-3

To reduce the number of pins I have multiplexed a 10 pin 2 digit 7- segment display as shown in the circuit diagram.

The problem is that the displays brightness is very poor (I'm not even using a resistor), only 2 of the displays is visible and the other two are very low.

I'm not using PWM mechanism to run the digits, I'm just simultaneously switching them.

Is there an easy fix as i have only two days to make it presentable.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Could you please provide the essential parts of your code to make the reader understand how you operate the whole thing?

Comment: LED brightness is determined by current. My first guess for your issue is that the MSC23S17 isn't supplying enough current per pin to drive 4 seven-segment LEDs.

Comment: You could try using transistors to drive the LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that multiplexing means you only actively drive a single digit at a time. The brightness you get is inversely proportional to the number of digits. If you multiplex 7 digits, each digit will have 1/7 of its original brightness, no matter how hard you try. If you need more brightness, use more IO extenders and less multiplexing.

Another limitation comes from the IO extenders you use. MSP23S17 can only sink 25 mA per pin, which is not a lot: if you have to drive all 7 segments at once, you'll get less than 4 mA per segment. Assuming standard LEDs which allow up to 20 mA of current, you just crippled the brightness by another 5 times in the worst case. Considering the brightness loss due to multiplexing, your LEDs have only 1/35th of their original brightness which I agree is not a lot.

You might want to use more powerful extenders, drive common lines with several IO pins in parallel (but beware, if you bridge two pins together, driving one of them low and the other one high will damage the IC), or use transistors to amplify the current.

The difference in brightness between individual displays may be explained by the software implementation of your multiplexing functionality. If done right, you should get equal brightness on all digits.